# php get the max(accNumber) and then increment by 1

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the highest number and then increment it by 1.
I get blank page, here is my code

```
   $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT max(accnum) FROM accounts");
        $query->execute();

       while($num = $query->fetchAll()){

        if($num[1] == null){

        $accnumber = "100001";

        }else{

        $accnumber = $num[1]++; 
    }
        echo $accnumber;
    }
```

what am i doing wrong here. Thanks

Comment: shouldn't that be `$num[0][0]`?  (Meaning the value of the first row, first column)

Comment: $num[0] is accID. i tried $num[0][0] its still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT max(accnum) FROM accounts");
        $query->execute();

       while($num = $query->fetchAll()){

        if($num[0] == null){

        $accnumber = "100001";

        }else{

        $accnumber = $num[0]++; 
    }
        echo $accnumber;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I added echo $accnumber[]; and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this ?

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT max(accnum)+1 as maximum FROM accounts");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($result['maximum'] == null) { 
    $result = "100001" 
} else { 
    $result = $accnumber['maximum'] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using [postincrement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php); that is, the `++` is after the variable, so [it's not updated until after the assignment is complete](http://codepad.org/xI10bun9).

Simply use this instead:

```
$accnumber = $num[1] + 1;
```

That way, `$num` isn't affected, and your value will be correct.

Since you're getting a blank page, this may not be the issue. So, you may also want to reconsider how you handle the values; you seem to be mixing strings and integers, and that probably won't end well. I'd suggest using only integers. Also, you should be using `$num[0]`, since you're fetching the first value of a zero-based array:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT max(accnum) FROM accounts");
$query->execute();

while($num = $query->fetchAll()){

    if($num[0] == null){

        $accnumber = 100001;
    }else{

        $accnumber = intval($num[0]) + 1;
    }
    echo $accnumber;
}
```

Comment: im getting this error Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/test.php on line 9 100001

Comment: @kaneo Good point; since arrays are zero-based, and you're only fetching one value, you need to use `$num[0]`. I've updated the answer.